# Change bootstrap navbar link color based on position on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm slightly confused. I've created multiple page websites before using bootstrap and I'd include the navbar markup on every page and set the current page link to the .active class so that I could access it and highlight it nicely.

I'm now working on a single page website and it has a sticky ("fixed") navbar. I have it set up to scroll using jQuery to specific sections down the page based on that sections ID. However, how to I access the "current" navbar link I'm currently at?

Basically, as I scroll down the page I'll go through all the links and I'd like the link to change color based on what section it is in. Do I need to use jQuery to change the class of the link? Or does bootstrap have something built in for this?

Comment: can you show code to us (may be in jsfiddle ) otherwise its hard to answer your question

Comment: Check the page scroll position with the div/content offset?

Comment: With no issue/problem or source code posted I can only recommend looking into `window.pageYOffset` and the content offset, for example `offsetTop`. I have a site using the same sort of menu done in pure javascript, works well but i believe jQuery would be easier as most of it is done for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for Bootstrap's Scrollspy. It will set the `active` class in the navbar `li` element when the current scroll position matches the id of an element on the page.

First set-up the Scrollspy on the BODY tag. Offset is the height of the fixed navbar:

```
$('body').scrollspy({
  target: '#myNavbar',
  offset: 50
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="myNavbar">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
       <li><a href="#section1">One</a></li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#section2">Two</a></li>
       <li><a href="#section3">Three</a></li>
       ..
    </ul>
 </div>   

 <div id="section1">Section One</div>
 <div id="section2">Section Two</div>
 <div id="section3">Section Three</div>
```

Then override this CSS to change the .active link color:

```
.navbar-nav li>a:hover,.navbar-nav li>a:focus,.navbar-nav li.active {
    background-color:#000;
}
```

Example: http://www.codeply.com/go/v1AEOlZMtC

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! I was sure how to explain it / word it but that's definitely it. Like I said I've done it with multiple pages, as active is set per page, but on a one page layout I knew the active class would need to be changed in real time.